# How to Setup a File Server and use it over Internet?

Tags: networking, nas, time-capsule, fiber, ddns

I want to Setup a FileServer so that i could Access/Edit my Files over Internet. I'm having Apple Airport Time Capsule of 3TB Storage filled almost 70% of Personal Files and Movies.And Im having a PC which is probably old as Compared to Today's Computers & it is also filled with some Data, So i want to use both of them as a Server.

Im using FTTH Internet which is having a ONT Device from that i connected TimeCapsule for Wifi. Please Help me. Simple ones i can Google it like setting up NAS server and all. But it seems like tough thats why posting here (Requires Expertise in Networking).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're leaving the PC with/connected to the Time Capsule, it may be easiest to use Teamviewer, https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows.aspx free and available for basically all OS's , this will let you remote log into the PC and access it and everything it is connected to.  You can also copy files between the desktops so you can transfer them to/from the connected computer easily.  I even use teamviewer on my smartphone to connected/transfer necessary files.

The other more complicated option would be to set up an FTP server on the PC.  https://filezilla-project.org/  free and for most OS's as well.  It does a lot of the work for you but if you have a locked-down firewall on your router and don't know how to change it you could have issues.